# Getting different X coordinates for points which are displayed right next to each other?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, coordinates, line, xy

I want to connect two points with a line with the "XY to line" tool. Therefore I add the XY coordinates with the "add XY coordinates" tool. Although the points are right next to each other the X values of one of the point layers are far too high. I can tell which layer is causing the problem as when I run the "XY to line" tool the line starts at the right point but goes to the middle of nowhere.

See the images below.

[image]
[image]

---

I already fixed it, I projected one of the point layers to the wrong coordinate system.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please add the all-important name of the software you're using to the tag list.

Comment: Please also provide the projection of you layers & dataframe.